# Two dimensional strings in C++

Tags: c++, stl, matrix

I want to write something like 2d strings in C++. 
I tried with :

```
vector< vector<string> > table;
        int m,n,i,j;
        string s;
        cin>>n>>m;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
                for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
                        cin>>s;
                        table[i][j] = s;
                }
        }
        cout << "\n\n\n\n";
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
                for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
                        cout<<table[i][j]<<" ";
                }
                cout<<"\n";
        }
```

no compile errors, but when i enter input like:

```
10 20
.....#..............
.....#..............
.....#..............
.....#..............
######..............
.......###..........
.......#.#..........
.......###...#######
.............#.....#
.............#######
```

It gives me segmentation fault. Why ? What's wrong ? And how it should be done so it would work correctly ? Thank you.

Comment: One way to find the line where the problem occurs is to use `vector::at(size_t)` instead of `vector::operator[]`, as an exception will be thrown where an invalid index is accessed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question seems to imply that the data structure needed is a set of `n` lines with `m` characters each. There are two ways to think of this -- as an `nxm` char matrix, or as `n` `m`-character vectors (and a string is similar but not identical to `vector<char>`).

So it seems you don't want a `vector` of `vector`s of `string`s, you want either a `vector` of `vector`s of `char`s, or just a `vector` of `string`s.

In any event, you have to allocate the appropriate amount of space before using table[i][j] or (slightly more idiomatic c++, but not necessary in this case since `m` and `n` are known beforehand) use something like `push_back` to add to the end.

Note also that the `cin>>s` reads an entire *line* from `stdin` (which makes the `vector<string>` solution a bit easier to deal with, I think).

Comment: Not necessarily, consider a grid/table in a spreadsheet with a formula in each cell. That's a 2d array of strings

Comment: But in this case (i.e., from the sample input) the questioner seems to want a 2d array of chars.

Comment: The problem isn't that he couldn't get away with a `vector<vector<string>>` -- part of the problem is that `cin>>s` is going to read in a whole line at a time. If he wasn't segfaulting, he'd run out of input before he filled everything up.

Comment: agreed; the point about pre-allocation or push_back is actually more important, although the fact that the questioner didn't really understand the correct data structure implies fuzzy thinking in general!...

Comment: Although it's true that `cin >> s` will read an entire line given the input in the question, it might be worth pointing out that it really only reads up to the first whitespace character - for reading a line even in the presence of whitespace there's the global `std::getline` function.

Answer (score 4):

When inserting something new into a `vector`, you can't just allocate by index - you need to use the `push_back` method or something similar.

```
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            vector<string> row;
            for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
                    cin>>s;
                    row.push_back(s);
            }
            table.push_back(row);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `vector` class has a ctor that takes the size and an element, so:

```
vector< vector<char> > table(ROW_COUNT, vector<char>(COLUMN_COUNT, '.'));
```

would initialize a vector containing `ROW_COUNT` copies of the vector passed as the second argument, which contains `COLUMN_COUNT` times `.`.

Answer (score 1):

It is an error to index a vector that you haven't inserted into yet.

So taking a more easy example:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v[0] = 3;//bad, v[0] doesn't exist yet
```

Correct:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(3);
int x = v[0];//ok
```

But in your case you are first inserting into a vector and then pushing the whole vector into the other vector.

Answer (score 1):

I think a `vector<vector<char> >` would be better suitable for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You `vector`s are still empty and you probably wan't to . You can either append values using e.g. `push_back()` or init them with a suitable size:

```
std::cin >> n >> m;
typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVec;
std::vector<StringVec> table(n, StringVec(m));
```

As others mentioned though, `std::string` might not be what you really need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `char s; cin.get(s);` instead of `string s; cin>>s;`, becuase `cin>>s` will read a whole word (in your sample this is equivalent to a whole line) at a time.

Additionally, you need to do something to get the size of each array right. In your code you have a vector of 0 vectors of 0 strings. For example:

```
vector< vector<string> > table;
int m,n,i,j;
char s;
cin>>n>>m;
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    table.push_back(vector<string>());
        for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
                cin.get(s);
                table[i].push_back(string(1,s));
        }
}
cout << "\n\n\n\n";
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
                cout<<table[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create vector of elements, to add elements you must use `v.insert(v.end(), s)`. and finnaly (when you have full row data). you must write `tables.insert(tables.end(), v)`